# How to keep subprocess.Popen console open after crashing on Windows?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, console, popen

My goals is to call the main program with several different arguments for each `Popen` process, each with its own console window. However, once a crash is encountered, it closes that console, and I'd really really like to keep it open instead.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
import time

for i in range(1, 5):
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "main.py", str(i), str(i)], close_fds=False, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Is it possible to make a new process with `subprocess.Popen` and keep the console open for me to read errors?
Link to [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A console window is hosted by an instance of conhost.exe (Win 7+), which exits when no process is attached to it. So you just need to attach a 2nd python.exe process to each console and have it wait. Here's a simple demonstration script that makes the waiter process wait on the primary process (i.e. the parent of the worker process):

```
import sys

# If started with a pid, wait for the associated process to exit.
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    import ctypes
    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
    pid = int(sys.argv[1])
    hproc = kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0, pid)
    if not hproc:
        sys.exit(ctypes.get_last_error())
    print('waiter: waiting')
    kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(hproc, -1)
    sys.exit(0)

import os
import subprocess
print('worker: start')
# The waiter waits on our parent (ppid).
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, sys.argv[0], str(os.getppid())])
print('worker: exit')
```

For example:

```
>>> import sys, subprocess
>>> flags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
>>> p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'main.py'], creationflags=flags)
>>> p.wait()
0
>>> exit()
```

The worker process re-spawns itself to wait on its parent. Then it exits with a return code of 0. The console window closes after `exit()`.

You could also spawn the waiter instance from the primary process. In this case, pass the PID of the worker to the waiter. Then the waiter can call [`FreeConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150) and [`AttachConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952) to attach itself to the worker's console. This is more complicated, but it makes it easy for the primary process to terminate the waiter.

Comment: it looks complicated. Is there any issue with `cmd /k "python main.py {i} {i} && exit 0"` (+/- escaping)?

Comment: Thanks for solving my thread. Tested, it works finely. Though, Python C extensions and C++ and Windows programming is, I'm not good at it right now, so it's for the future I guess.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, you could do that, but then it's more complicated to wait on or terminate the worker process since you have a handle for cmd.exe instead of python.exe. Plus the way I showed guarantees that all of the consoles exit with the primary process. With an instance of cmd.exe you'd have to use a Job object to accomplish that.

Comment: @eryksun: how is it more complicated to wait? You wait for the `cmd` process using `p.wait()`. On success it exits itself. On failure, OP don't want to terminate it programmatically as I understand (*"I'd really really like to keep it open instead"*). Anyway it shouldn't be more complex to terminate than any process that may spawn other processes (I don't see a restriction that `main.py` can't use subprocesses in turn).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, it seemed to me that ivarsj10s just wants the console windows left open for debugging (not a great design, but I'm just answering the question at hand), and I figured it would be convenient to not have to manually close them all. When the primary process exits or dies in my example, all of the waiters also exit and the console windows close automatically.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, also, if you run the worker process via cmd.exe you need to find the worker's PID, or get it via an IPC mechanism if you need to wait on it and get its exit code; that's just shifting the complexity from one place to another. If the worker starts additional processes, that is a problem for the worker to solve, not the problem of the primary process.

Comment: @eryksun (1) if it is only for debugging then OP may use different commands in release/debug modes: `if debug: cmd = 'cmd /k "%s && exit 0"' % cmd` (2) I don't see why do you need worker's PID here (use YAGNI principle -- don't introduce additional complexity unless you must -- write the most straightforward code that could possibly work and iff the requirements expand then and only then expand your solution to accommodate new requirements)

Answer (score 0):

By changing the stdout and the stderr you can actually get the information you want, for instance using `pdb` ([python's built in debugging library](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pdb.html)). I like this approach as opposed to keeping a window open as it is portable to headless environments.

As per the [Popen docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) set `stdin` to `subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr` to `subprocess.STDOUT` if you want both regular and error output captured in the same buffer. I personally prefer this for debugging. Otherwise set both to `PIPE`.
Don't forget to keep track of your `Popen` objects, otherwise you cannot inspect them. Your example would look something like this:

```
import subprocess
import time
import pdb

processes = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "main.py", str(i), str(i)], 
                     close_fds=False, 
                     creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    processes.append(process)
    time.sleep(3)
pdb.set_trace()
```

Mind that the consoles that are created will not show output, as it has been rerouted.
Now when you drop into the debugger, processes should be a list of `subprocess.Popen` objects like (your list will be longer of course):

```
(Pdb) processes
[<subprocess.Popen object at 0x000002D359BD6AF0>, <subprocess.Popen object at 0x000002D359BD6F10>]
```

Poll the processes to find out which ones have exited:

```
(Pdb) processes[0].poll()
1
(Pdb) processes[1].poll()
(Pdb)
```

This output tells us the first process in the list has exited, the second one is still running.
If you want a nicely printed output capture, do the following:

```
(Pdb) print(processes[0].stdout.read().decode())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\dicom-nifti-message-service\tests\dicom_nifti_app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from conftest import set_progress
  File "C:\Projects\dicom-nifti-message-service\tests\conftest.py", line 46, in <module>
      from tests.dicom_nifti_app_config import config as config_
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.dicom_nifti_app_config'
```

The command looks a bit convoluted, but the `Popen.stdout` attribute is a buffer, and you call `read()` on it to get it as a bytestring. Now you call `decode()` on it to get a string. Use `print()` to not see characters like `\n` in the output, but actually interpret them as newlines etc.

Small note:  Note that to access the output of the running process while debugging you have to kill it first! Do it as follows, or check the docs for some alternative ways.

```
(Pdb) processes[1].poll()
(Pdb) processes[1].kill()
(Pdb) processes[1].poll()
1
(Pdb)
```

And if you are not interested in live debugging you could:

- use this method to write the captured output to files
- or maybe even easier, log to a file from the program(s) you are running in a subprocess